# ZAP Daemon -quickout does't produce report

Tags: localhost, report, daemon, zap

i'm running ZAP Daemon locally to undertand it better. 
I'm able to see results if i open with the browser the UI (localhost:8090/UI/core/other/htmlreport).
But if i use the option "-quickout C:\Users\test.html", the report is not produced.

Do you have any clue here?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -quickout command line option doesnt apply to the daemon mode, it is only relevant for the -quickurl option.
Use the relevant API calls instead.

Comment: Hi Simon, yes sorry actually i misinterpreted this command. By using the proper API it works. It works for the moment only locally, so i've to investigate how it will work with Docker.